# Using files from Windows on Ubuntu when using Windows installer

Tags: installation, windows, uninstall

I just installed Ubuntu using the Windows installer. I did so onto my main hard drive.

I want to find and use programs that were installed on my windows before I installed Ubuntu. How do I do this?

If not, how do I delete Ubuntu? I had a look through the "devices" and it only came up with my other partition of my hard drive, drive `D:` (which I don't use; I use `C:`, which is what I downloaded Ubuntu onto) and this other 210 MB volume thing with folders saying boot and system volume information.

I had a look around in that and couldn't find an uninstall function.

If you could achieve the first objective which is to use programs from the same hard drive Ubuntu was loaded onto (drive `C:`) that would be great. If it's not possible, why not? And if so, how do I uninstall Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

If you used WUBI to install Ubuntu, boot into Windows, and in Control panel choose **Uninstall a program**. Find Ubuntu and click Uninstall.

If that fails, you may try uninstalling with the [Uninstall-Ubuntu.exe](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=Uninstall-Ubuntu.exe).

More information on the [WubiGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide).

Answer (score 1):

You can run some windows programs with wine, but not directly from your windows installation.

Ubuntu is not a drop in replacement for windows, in general does not run windows programs well, and if you want to run Ubuntu I suggest you look at linux native alternates to your windows programs:

http://www.linuxalt.com/

http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20070701111340544/Equivalents.html

If you simply wish to access files / data it should be located at /host

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_access_the_Windows_drives.3F

To uninstall see:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Uninstallation